# Running Ant build from Gradle, how to pass -lib argument?

Tags: ant, gradle, build.gradle

I want to slowly migrate to a better build and dependency resolution process, we are currently using Ant with local file dependencies.

We chose to migrate to gradle ,so as a first step I would like to simply run my current ant build from a gradle sript. But i dont know how to pass the -lib classpath to ant. Im getting errors of missing dependencies.

This is my gradle.build:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

task someProperties  {
    ext.LIBS_CATW = "backend/java-src/lib"
    ext.LIB_SERVLET = "/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/lib/servlet-api.jar" 
}

dependencies {
    compile files('/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/lib/servlet-api.jar')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'backend/java-src/lib', include: '*.jar')
}
```

I use this shell script to run ant from command line.

```
#!/bin/bash

export JAVA_HOME="/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6.0/Home"

ROOT_DIR="/Users/poolebu/catwizardMultitenant/catwizard/catwBackend/branches/branchSpringSecurity/"

DIR_MT="$ROOT_DIR"

LIBS_CATW="$ROOT_DIR/backend/java-src/lib"

LIB_SERVLET="/usr/local/apache-tomcat-7.0.32/lib/servlet-api.jar"

ANT_TARGET="allButFlex"

cd $DIR_MT

ant -lib $LIBS_CATW -lib $LIB_SERVLET $ANT_TARGET
```

This is one of the many dependency errors I´m getting

```
[ant:javac] /Users/poolebu/catwizardMultitenant/catwizard/catwBackend/branches/branchSpringSecurity/backend/java-src/catw-common/src/com/bamboo/common/factory/SpringFactory.java:5: error: package flex.messaging does not exist
[ant:javac] import flex.messaging.FlexFactory;
[ant:javac]                      ^
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is right way. You will get into running ant from gradle and waste a lot of time to get it working. Try to do it *gradle way* from scratch and ask questions if You don't know how to do something particular.